# Rocker switch panel wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, battery

I am looking to wire a boat rocker switch panel to a 12 volt deep cycle battery for my canoe. I have three switched on the rocker switch panel. One will be for navigation lights, one will be for a small bilge pump and the third will be for a small light bar.

The rocker switch panel didn't come with instructions and I was looking for how to wire it. I been looking online but it seems like every picture and graph I see, the more confused I get.

I know the top wires, the red and black, go to my 12 volt battery power source but besides that I am lost. I have no idea what the yellow and blue wires are for. I found that the panel came with 3 red wires that I'm assuming connect to each of the bottom left poles on each of the three switches.

Each of my three appliances that I want to connect to this switch panel has a red and black wire.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many terminals on the back of the switch ? How many switch positions? If the switch’s are lighted 2 terminals are probably for the lights. Then it goes to the switch terminals on my boat I have 3 position for example electronics on top position center off bottom running lights and electronics , or the windshield wipers up is high center off down low , or bilge up is on  middle off down auto. My switches are double pole double throw 6 connections the center is common and opposite direction of the handle connects to common so if the handle is up the center and bottom of both contact sets on.

Comment: The switches are lighted and there are two positions on and off. There are five terminals on the back of each switch. I just found a video that shows you join the black and yellow wires together and then the red and blue wires together. The red wire from each application goes to the bottom left pole of each switch and the black wire from each application goes directly to the black pole on the battery. Does that sound accurate?

Comment: Whoever wired the switch wires was either a moron or was just doing demonstration wiring.  It's completely and obviously wrong.  No wonder you are confused!

Comment: Have you tried to use a continuity tester to figure out the wiring of the switches you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 5 pin gang rocker switch panels can be a little tricky to get your head around alright!

**Here is what the 5 pins wire to:**

Positive IN for LED backlights (always on)

Negative OUT for LED backlights (always on)

Positive IN for appliance

Positive OUT for appliance

Negative OUT for LED lamp (Turn ON when switched)

In the image you have shared, blue and red wires are positives, black and yellow are negatives.

Here's an in-depth guide I wrote on [switch panel wiring](https://www.thevanconversion.com/post/how-to-wire-a-campervan-switch-panel), it shows you how to wire up these types of gang rocker switch panels! :)

Comment: Can you disclose whatever relationship you have with the site that's hosting the post you're linking to?